# Processing Java: How do you detect if the mouse was dragged through a variable

Tags: java, processing

I understand that code inside `Processing`'s `mouseDragged()` function will run if the mouse is moved and pressed at the same time. I was wondering how I could detect such movement through a variable since `Processing` doesn't provide a corresponding variable for `mouseDragged()` unlike `mousePressed()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution specific to `Processing` would be to create the variable that stores whether the user dragged the mouse or not. Under `mouseDragged()`, the variable is set to **true**. Inside the `draw()` function, if the mouse is not pressed, the variable is set to **false**.

*Example*:

```
boolean mouseDragged = false;

void draw()
{
    if (mousePressed == false)
    {
        mouseDragged = false;
    }

    println(mouseDragged);
}

void mouseDragged()
{
    mouseDragged = true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need the `MouseMotionListener` instead. It has two methods:

> 1. Mousedragged
> 2. MouseMoved

Answer (score -1):

There is https://processing.org/reference/mouseMoved_.html which sounds like the right thing.

Comment: That's a function, not a variable. You'll need to self-implement a way to create the variable.